# MySQL Convert a Substring_index and then check if it equals a value in another column

Tags: mysql, if-statement, data-conversion

I have a column that has a tibcoofferid in the format of 12345.
Another column of contains tibcoaddevent in the format Add_12345.

I'd like an output column that checks if the tibcoofferid equals the number after the _ in the tibcoaddevent.

I have attempted the following, however the AddEvent check is being flagged as False, even though the two values match.  Can anyone help flag what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT tibcoofferid, tibcoaddevent
    , CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tibcoaddevent,'_',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num
    , IF (tibcoofferid = 'num', 'True', 'False') AS AddEvent
FROM offer_360 
WHERE tibcoofferid IN (13979, 13980, 13900, 13352, 12709)
```

Output:

| tibcoofferid | tibcoaddevent | num | AddEvent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12709 | Add_12709 | 12709 | False |
| 13352 | Add_13352 | 13352 | False |
| 13900 | Add_13900 | 13900 | False |
| 13979 | Add_13979 | 13979 | False |
| 13980 | Add_13980 | 13980 | False |

Also, is it possible to do this without the 'num' column being output like in my attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Rephrase the logic to `tibcoaddevent = Add_<tibcoofferid>`:

```
SELECT
  tibcoofferid,
  tibcoaddevent,
  case when tibcoaddevent = concat('Add_', tibcoofferid) then 'True' else 'False' end AS AddEvent
FROM offer_360 
WHERE ...
```